# Can we use InternetExplorerDriver Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can we use

`InternetExplorerDriver Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

How it is different from initiating instance as below:

`WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver()`

In terms of functionality of the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Well, overall concept here is `coding to interface` instead of `coding to implementation`. Both of above will work but the first approach is gives you extra advantage.

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Doing as above will allow you at later stage to change the declaration to some other concrete class.E.g.

`driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

However, providing the reference of concrete implementations (`IneternetExplorer driver = new InternetExplorerDriver()`) will restrict you to use the specific behaviour of InternetExplorer class only and at later stage if you would like to swapping it to other concrete implementation (for example ChromeDriver,FirefoxDriver) will become difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

By this you can access Methods and attribute of `Webdriver` class while

```
InternetExplorerDriver Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

It limits you to Methods and attribute  of `InternetExplorerDriver` class